# How can I convert GB and MB data string to GB(number) in Google sheet?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, byte, excel-2010

I have below data in string format

```
Size
670.2mb
668.4mb
3.2gb
1.1gb
479.7mb
```

I want to convert this column in below format

```
Sizw in GB    Size in MB
0.6544        670.2
0.6527        668.2
3.2           3276.8
1.1           1126.4
0.4684        479.7
```

---

how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

#### Explanation:

- Use [REGEXMATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292?hl=en) to check whether the value contains `mb` or `gb`.
- Use [LEFT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094079?hl=en) to remove the last two characters in the value (`mb`/`gb`).
- Use [IFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014145?hl=en) to divide by 1000 or not depending on the original value and the output column.

#### Formula:

```
={{"Size in GB","Size in MB"};
  ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR({
    IFS(REGEXMATCH(A2:A, "mb"), LEFT(A2:A,LEN(A2:A)-2)/1000,REGEXMATCH(A2:A, "gb"), LEFT(A2:A,LEN(A2:A)-2)),
    IFS(REGEXMATCH(A2:A, "gb"), LEFT(A2:A,LEN(A2:A)-2)*1000,REGEXMATCH(A2:A, "mb"), LEFT(A2:A,LEN(A2:A)-2))
  }))
}
```

[image]

Comment: Second column formula should be *1000 for gb? Also should be * 1024 strictly speaking.

Comment: @TomSharpe Yep, my bad. Answer updated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "\d+(?:\.\d+)?")*
 VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(?i)[a-z]+$"), 
 {{"mb"; "gb"}, {1; 1024}}, {2, 2}, )/{1024, 1}))
```

[image]